# Recursion in Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

I was trying to solve a problem in tree,And stuck in recursion and write a code.
But i cant't figure out that why it's giving this out ! someone help how to code
gives this output
My program is x=0,y=0

```
int height1(node *root,int x,int y)

{ 

 int val;

    if(root==NULL)
    return 1;
    else
    {
        x=x+height1(root->left,x,y);
        y=y+height1(root->right,x,y);
        printf("x=%d and y=%d %d\n",x,y,root->data);
        if(x>y)
            return x;
            else
                return y;
    }
```

it's just a rough work to understand flow of recursion.
Input of tree traversing is 50 40 70 45 30 44 48 and value of

```
       x  y  root->data 
      1   1    30 
      2   1    44
      4   1    48
      3    4    45
      1    4    40
      5     1    70
      4    5     50
```

why it going out in this way ,in my way it should add y and x each time so value should increase,

Please give me some advise ,because every time i solve a tree problem i always 
stuck in recursion, can anyone suggest what is right approach.

I understand that to figure out base condition is important, and i know it how to find.But can't get how the output came.

I know that here are many most experienced programmers
and i want that please give me some advice because i think they also faced some problems in recursion ,so how they solve this.How they solve recursive problem when any new one come.

Should i refer some book or should i just solve some programs.
So Please i want your advise so i can become good in this.

Comment: this would be a lot simpler to understand if you atleast explained what that (incomplete) code is supposed to do

Comment: It's just a rough code to get the flow of program . when i was trying to get the height of tree and stuck so to understand i wrote that rough code.

Answer (score 1):

This code has a rather strange architecture in general. You could leave the two int arguments away, they are useless. Next problem: this code doesn't count any nodes except for leaves. And this code has some logical mistakes aswell (example: `if(root == NULL) return 1;` would lead to counting nodes that don't even exist). In general this could be implemented a lot simpler:

```
int height1(node *root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;

    int l = height1(root->left);
    int r = height1(root->right);

    return (l < r ? r : l) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that there is no need in the function argument and i can define them anywhere else,But does your code and mine will give the same output :) if yes then how?

Comment: @SachinGodara no i don't think so, though this code will give a correct result. In general the print-statement is rather confusing, since the nodes are printed from the leaves to the root. I don't think it'll result in the same output. Actually i'm still trying to understand how x and y in your code can actually get bigger than 1

Comment: i am returning the value which is bigger,and adding it to previous values of x and y,.and that's what i want to know that how this code giving this answer.

Comment: @SachinGodora I understand the basic idea of the code, since it's the same as mine. My algorithm even traverses the tree in the same order as yours does. I think i got the thing with `x` and `y` (atleast how the values are generated), though i still dont get the purpose behind it

Comment: Let me speak truth i was just writing a code to get the height, each step by step i wrote code,then came on this code, i know that it was wrong but instead of that i just stuck that why and how compiler showing this output, how to program flow goes,because each time i try to solve trees problem i stuck on the same think ,that why i ask this , that how the flow goes of this program,and how should i treat a recursive problem (new one) each time i saw it? how a experience programmer think?should i refer some book if yes then which one?that's why i asked this.

Comment: @SachinGodara ok, in that case, the simplest would probably be to simply debug the code and look through it step by step. I can't give you any help with the thinking, since everyone thinks differently about recursion. Topic references: IMO a book won't help you a lot with understanding recursion, you'll have to practice in order to understand it. You could try practicing with this tutorial: http://codingbat.com/java/Recursion-1 or search another one on your own

Comment: can you tell me that if i use printf statement after second line,of your code then how will be the flow of program ,means in above one value of l,r after each iteration

Comment: @SachinGodara you mean after the `return 0;` statement? it'll first print the value of `root`, afterwards proceed with the left child of `root` and once all children of the left child of `root` have been traversed proceed with the right children of `root`